# How to Get Last Seven Days in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying last seven days record using below query, but it does not work.

```php
<?php

DB::table('data_table')
    ->select(DB::raw('SUM(fee) as counter, left(DATE(created_at),10) as date'))
    ->whereIn('user_id', $descendants)
    ->whereRaw('DATE(created_at) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('left(DATE(created_at),10)'))
    ->get();
```

How to make it correct?

Comment: _Does not work?_ Is not a very helpful description of a problem! Does it error, if so let see the error message. Does it produce the wrong resultset, if do let see the inputs and the result it does produce

Comment: Looks like a typo: `=` should be `>` or `>=`

Comment: Also not sure you need the `left` in `DB::raw('left(DATE(created_at),10)')` as `DATE()` should produce a valid 10 char date for you anyway

Answer (score 1):

->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(7)->startOfDay())->get()

Comment: Laravel has specific whereDate() not sure if needed to call this?

Comment: With whereDate he also needs what date was 7 days ago, also he is using the created the created_at column which contains time.